# How can I fire initComplete on table draw?

Tags: jquery, function, datatable, initialization

When I load my page my alert "init complete" is fired.

```
  var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
  ...
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      alert("init complete");
    }
  });
```

But when I later want to redraw my datatable in a function, the alert "init complete" is not fired:

```
function filter(value) {
  table
  .search( '' )
  .columns().search( '' )
  .columns(3)
  .search(value, true, false)
  .draw();
}
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function (e) {
   filter($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Init complete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) is fired only one time: `when your table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn, particularly when using an ajax data source`. That's the reason why it doesn't run when you redraw your table.

So I think that you need something like [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback): `It can be useful to take an action on every draw event of the table`

Note: If you use drawCallback you dont need initComplete, when table is completely load it fires drawCallback